# EclipseLink Sybase : Existing Index is not used

Tags: eclipselink, glassfish-3, jpql, sap-ase

When i query the booking table via JPA / EclipseLink and search for a specific placeID the existing index myindex is not used. Sybase decides to make a table scan.

When I copy the sql from the Glassfish Log File to a sql-editor and run it there it uses the index. ????

Simplified sql:

```
create table pub.BOOKING(
   bookID numeric(10) identity,
   placeID smallint not null
)

create index idx_BOOKING_PLACEID on pub.BOOKING(placeID)
```

** SHOWPLAN from Sybase ASE when running from JPQL **

```
Die Art der Abfrage ist SELECT.           
VON TABELLE  pub.BOOKING                           
Verschachtelte Iteration.                 
Tabellen-Scan.                            
Vorwärts-Scan.                             
Positionierung am Tabellenanfang.          
Parallel mit einem 5-Weg-Hash-Scan ausgefü 
Für die Datenseiten wird eine I/O-Größe vo 
Mit LRU Pufferersetzungsstrategie für Date 
Parallele Netzpufferzusammenführung.
```

** JPQL Query **

```
Placement p = em_local.find(Placement.class, 207);
TypedQuery<Booking> query = em_local.createQuery("select b from Booking b where b.placement = :place", Booking.class);
query.setParameter("place", p);
List<Booking> list = query.getResultList();
```

** SHOWPLAN from Sybase ASE when running in a sql editor **

```
     VON TABELLE
         pub.BOOKING
     Verschachtelte Iteration.
     Index: idx_BOOKING_PLACEID
    Vorwärts-Scan.
    Positionierung durch Schlüssel.
    Schlüssel sind:
        placeID  AUFST
    Parallel mit einem 5-Weg-Hash-Scan ausgeführt.
    Für die Index-Blattebenen wird eine I/O-Größe von 2 KByte verwendet.
    Mit LRU Pufferersetzungsstrategie für Index-Blattseiten.
    Für die Datenseiten wird eine I/O-Größe von 2 KByte verwendet.
    Mit LRU Pufferersetzungsstrategie für Datenseiten.
```

** Requested Select from logfile **

```
20131118 08:44:59,845 FINE     sql      SELECT bookID, placeID FROM pub.BOOKING WHERE (placeID = ?)       bind => [207]
```

** After some investigations **

It looks like the smallint datatype from sybase is the problem here.

Eclipselink queries like this:

```
declare @p0 int
select @p0 = 5
select * from pub.BOOKING where placeID = @p0
```

If I write declare @p0 smallint the index is used.
If I write declare @p0 int the index is not used.

So I guess JPA is mapping Integer to int. And that's causing the problem.

How can I tell JPA to use smallint for this column?

Comment: Put following properties in your `persistence.xml`:

    <property name="eclipselink.logging.level" value="FINE"/>
    <property name="eclipselink.logging.level.sql" value="FINE"/>
    <property name="eclipselink.logging.parameters" value="true"/>

Then show us how Eclipselink is translating your JPQL query to SQL.

Comment: i added it into the question above

Comment: Weird. Sometimes the optimizer doesn't use an index because, the table is too short (e.g. has only 15 records) or the distribution (different values) is not ideal for using an index (e.g. you have a column which has only 2 different values 'm' and 'f' and both of them covers ~50% of the rows). Are you using the same database for GlassFish and interactive sql-editor? If yes, I cannot help you.

Comment: What you mean is just a result of the cost calculations. If table is very small it is less "expensive" to load the whole table then dealing arround with an index.    YES, :-) it is the same database and same table ...     I also test a native sql instead jpql. It's factor 1000 faster. Means it has nothing to do the the sql editor. It has to do with the JPQL.

Comment: I maybe found the problem. But I don't know how to solve. Please read the last part of above.

Answer (score 1):

The Problem is the Smallint DataType.

I used a Integer in the Entity Class to access it. It let JPA query like this:

```
declare @p0 int
select @p0 = 5
select bookID, placeID from pub.BOOKING where placeID = @p0
```

This let's sybase decide that the "where" statement is not a Standard Argument (SARG). That means it cannot use the corresponding index because the datatype of the index is 2 byte and the param is 4 byte.

Using a Short datatype in the Entity solved the problem.

** Some queries i made on Sybase ASE to figure out what wrong **

You must install MDA Feature of Sybase first.

That show's if you have a table scan:

```
select * 
from master.dbo.monSysPlanText 
order by SPID, BatchID, SequenceNumber
```

This show's you what query JPA is really sending to the ASE:

```
select * 
from master.dbo.monSysSQLText
```